# Unexpected behavior setting non-default I2C address for HT16K33 LED Driver

Tags: i2c, led-driver, led-matrix

The [HT16K33](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ht16K33v110.pdf) is an I2C controlled LED driver.
The data sheet shows a standard way of setting the I2C slave address:
[image]

I have implemented this circuit, but it does not work as expected.
For the default address 0x70, A0, A1, A2 are open. At the default address everything works fine.
When I try to move to 0x71 by closing the A0 jumper in the example above, the device seems to remain at address 0x70.
It responds at 0x70, and addressing I2C at 0x71 fails with no response.
In addition to not responding to the correct address, closing the A0 jumper also introduces a display artifact.   The display segment corresponding to A0 (ROW2) is illuminated in each of the digit positions except the first (driven by COM0).

I thought perhaps the diode was shorted, but after replacing it, I have the same issue.

Full schematic is below. Note that the HT16K33 is designed to sink current on the digit drivers (COM0-7), and source on the segment (ROW0-15). This is appropriate for a common cathode segment LED.  This circuit uses external drivers to drive a common anode LED.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Holtek chip has a button matrix scanning feature.

When the matrix pins are not driving a LED it can read buttons when row pins are set to inputs and they have an internal pull-down. The buttons and the I2C setting strap will set input high when button is pushed or the address jumper is closed, and the correct column output is driven high to scan them. So the Toshiba driver sees this address strap as high input and drives the LEDs because it does not know why the line went high. And since the column to scan that is high, only column 0 won't have the LEDs on, and all other columns will, as your column drivers also don't know why the pins are low, whether due driving or scanning.

Also the Toshiba chip has an internal pull-down on its inputs. The value is not stated but it can easily double the load on the address selection pins. Therefore the 39k resistors may not be enough to drive them, so you might need to bring the 39k resistor to a lower value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll have to study this more to understand why the same problem would not occur with directly driven LEDs.  I don't see any apparent workaround, so I'll explore using a 1 to 8 analog mux controlled by GPIOs to control the I2C SDA connection to the display boards (one at a time), and leave all the boards at the un-jumpered address of 0x70.